# Integral identity?

Tags: calculus, integration

Is this statement true? If so, I do not know why, can anyone explain please:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(k-x)^2} \,dx=\int_{-k}^k e^{-x^2} \,dx$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's see.

Let $y = k-x$. Then $\frac{dy}{dx} = -1$, so $dx = -dy$. As $x \to \pm \infty$, we have $y \to \mp \infty$ as well, so the limits swap.

Then, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(k-x)^2}\, dx = -\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} e^{-y^2}\, dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\, dy.$$

So I'd say not.

---

A different approach: consider that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-k)^2}\, dx = 1$ is the CDF of a normal random variable with mean $k$ and variance $\frac12$. Meanwhile, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\, dx = 1$ is the CDF of a normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\frac12$. We set them equal. Obviously, as the integrand is strictly positive, finite limits of integration would not yield equality.

Answer (score 11):

No. The first one is bigger. For the extreme case consider $k=0$.